# How to make Backbone's and MongoDB's ids work seamlessly?

Tags: php, mongodb, backbone.js

My Backbone app is communicating with a REST API built on top of MongoDB, so my objects' "natural" ids are really `MongoIDs`. When serialized into JSON, they look like:

```
"_id":{"$id":"505099e998dee4db11000001"}
```

The [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) mentions that you can specify another name than `id` for your Backbone model's id attribute (using `idAttribute`), however, as MongoIDs' string representations are nested, just using `idAttribute: '_id'` doesn't help in consuming JSON directly.

Is there a way around this, other than rewriting attributes on the server side?

*Update:*

Here's what I'm doing server-side:

```
$m = new Mongo();
$posts = $m->mydatabase->posts->find();

$out = array();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $out[] = $post;
}

echo json_encode($out);
```

I know I could do something like `$post['id'] = (string) $post['_id']; unset($post['_id']);` but it is precisely what I'm looking to avoid!

Comment: @AronWoost `"_id":{"$id":"505099e998dee4db11000001"}` (JSON encoding an object from MongoDB)

Comment: what is your REST api build around?  You may be able to simple change how it represents and ObjectID before sending it down to the client.

Answer (score 15):

This sounds like a good example for [`parse()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse).

Since your Mongo JSON ends up sending:

```
"_id":{"$id":"505099e998dee4db11000001"}
```

Why not use the Backbone parse to properly namespace the incoming data?

```
parse: function(response) {
    response.id = response._id['$id'];
    delete response._id;

    return response;
}
```

Or something like this. Similarly, since Backbone will be sending the id as JSON with 'id', your server might take that and "translate" it the other way.

If you want to use a different [id attribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute), `_id`, you would just replace the above parse with this code:

```
idAttribute: '_id',

parse: function(response) {
    response._id = response._id['$id'];

    return response;
}
```

Whatever works best for you. :-)

Comment: You might need to do something with [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) as well, depending on what the server expects to see as input of course.

Comment: The thing is I'd like to avoid having to "translate" data both client-side and server-side! I'm surprised that there's no simpler way to do this, especially as the Backbone doc mentions using `idAttribute` for MongoDB. Could it be that in some languages MongoIDs get JSON encoded as non-nested strings? (I'm using PHP)

Comment: What does your server expect?

Comment: @orangewarp I expanded my question with what I want to do server-side

Comment: @julien_c so, whatever the server throws at you, `parse()` handles it and turns it into something Backbone can understand. What you're asking is the other side of the equation? How to send back the data in a way you don't have to change anything on the server-end?

Comment: @orangewarp Yes, how would you do that? (sending the data back to the server in this form)

Comment: "Could it be that in some languages MongoIDs get JSON encoded as non-nested strings?"

PyMongo, for Python, nests the ObjectID in the same way you are seeing w/ PHP.

Answer (score 5):

It's better to do the conversion in the browser so you move the computation off from the server. So you'd want to create a base MongoModel, and then you can extend from MongoModel instead of Backbone.Model.

```
MongoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // this handle conversion between the mongo's _id and backbone id
    // this is best done on the client side to alleviate server load
    //_id : { "$oid" : ... } <--> id
    parse : function (response) {
        response.id = response._id.$oid;
        delete response._id;
        return response;
    },
    toJSON : function () {
        var
            json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.apply(this);
        json._id = {'$oid':json.id};
        delete json.id;
        return json;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at various suggested options I found the easiest would be to do what you want to avoid. (Using parse does work though)

```
$m = new Mongo();
$posts = $m->mydatabase->posts->find();

$out = array();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // populate an id field
    $post['id']=$post['_id']->{'$id'},
    $out[] = $post;
}

echo json_encode($out);
```

Keeping `$post['_id']` if you want your model to send it back when syncing.
I prefer correcting the API as more clients might want to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby I'm able to do the following:

```
items.find.to_a.map do |item|
  frombsonid(item)
end.to_json

def frombsonid(obj) obj.merge({'_id' => obj['_id'].to_s}) end
```

and when you get the data back, you can convert the string to BSON::ObjectId

```
def tobsonid(id) BSON::ObjectId.fromstring(id) end
```

So the idea is to replace _id in each item with a string version of BSON::ObjectId

In backbone you can add

```
idAttribute: "_id",
```

In PHP you will use different syntax and methods, but I believe it's quite possible to replicate this.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code is the REST API that Backbone will interact with, so *it* should handle the abstraction of Mongo's complex `_id` property to the simple `id` string you're looking for. That is definitely the API's job.

Backbone, or any other consumer of your API, should NOT know anything about Mongo or `_id`.

Why?
Because if you were to switch from Mongo to some other Db where there is no `_id`, then your API is still good because all that was ever exposed was `id`, which is super generic. So you're original idea was actually the best idea (although you'd want to abstract that piece of code into something that can be reused for all models, not just posts).